# I need to hold the power key for 15-30 seconds to power on my MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, bootloader

Starting after installing rEFInd on my Macbook Pro Retina (10,9) I need to press and hold the power key for a long time before even the blank which screen and boot up sound. How can I fix this? Here is my refind.conf: https://gist.github.com/drew-gross/7259648

I can also paste any other information that anyone thinks might be relevant. The only think I could think of was the refind.conf, since the problem happened right after installing refind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just passing on the solutions on how to avoid the 'famous 30 seconds wait' I came across [here](http://pastebin.com/n1MCYxsF) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164190/89420), which might be what you're experiencing:

The idea is to mount the EFI partition under Yosemite, which should be achieved by running in a terminal

> `mkdir /Volumes/esp`
>
> `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/esp`

Under the `esp` volume that you just mounted, rename the `EFI/refind` folder to `boot` and the `refind_x64.efi` file within to `bootx64.efi`, which should do the trick.

Hope this helps.